# render third party SVG in LWC not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, svg-icon

I have a zip file named svgFlags and inside svgFlags there is a folder named SVG with bunch of SVG files as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">;
    <use xlink:href={svgURL}></use>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
import SVG_FLAGS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/svgFlags';

get svgURL() {
    return SVG_FLAGS + '/svg/ad.svg';
}
```

Nothing renders on the page and no error at the console log, can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I assume your folder of SVGs has been added as a static resource called "svgFlags"?

Comment: Yes, I have added a zip folder named svgflags.